# Unrecognised Selector for calling method

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
- (NSDictionary*)convertMessage:(Message*)event
{
    // if this gets called then a derived class either didn't override this function or it called [super convertEvent:event]
    [self doesNotRecognizeSelector:_cmd];
    return nil;
}
```

I am expecting the result value will be nil.

```
-(void)calling{

 NSDictionary *dictionary  = [self convertMessage:evt];

}
```

But its saying unrecognized selector sent to instance for error block! when running!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the implementation of `[self doesNotRecognizeSelector:_cmd]` is to throw an exception. so the expected result is an exception raised. if you expect a nil return, then simply return nil in the method and do *not* call `doesNotRecognizeSelector:`

refer to [apple's doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> The runtime system invokes this method whenever an object receives an
>   aSelector message it can’t respond to or forward. This method, in
>   turn, raises an NSInvalidArgumentException, and generates an error
>   message.
>
> Any doesNotRecognizeSelector: messages are generally sent only by the
>   runtime system. However, they can be used in program code to prevent a
>   method from being inherited. For example, an NSObject subclass might
>   renounce the copy or init method by re-implementing it to include a
>   doesNotRecognizeSelector: message as follows:

```
- (id)copy {
    [self doesNotRecognizeSelector:_cmd];
}
```

> The _cmd variable is a hidden argument passed to every method that is the current selector;
>
> in this example, it identifies the selector for the copy method. This
>   code prevents instances of the subclass from responding to copy
>   messages or superclasses from forwarding copy messages—although
>   respondsToSelector: will still report that the receiver has access to
>   a copy method.
>
> If you override this method, you must call super or raise an
>   NSInvalidArgumentException exception at the end of your
>   implementation.
>   **In other words, this method must not return normally;it must always result in an exception being thrown.**

Comment: so it always throws an exception! which is NSInvalidArgumentException

Comment: yes. this is what suppose to happen when calling an unimplemented selector

Comment: thanks for the information it help my requriement. I do accept you answer

Answer (score 2):

To extend on @xlc0212's answer:

The original implementation of the method...

```
[self doesNotRecognizeSelector:_cmd];
return nil;
```

... was never expected to reach the `return` statement. As explained by @xlc0212 `doesNotRecognizeSelector` would throw an exception, leading to abnormal process termination.

The author of the implementation only put the `return` statement there to silence a compiler warning. A more modern and less confusing way to do this would be to tell clang that this point in code could not be reached:

```
- (NSDictionary*)convertMessage:(Message*)event
{
    [self doesNotRecognizeSelector:_cmd];
    __builtin_unreachable();
}
```